# implement decreasing key in binomial heap

Tags: binomial-heap

in the binomial heap structure, we know only the pointer that points to the min node, but how can I decrease the key of arbitrary node? in this case, first of all, I should find this node and then perform swapping with O(lgN) time.

I search online and many points out how to decrease node but does not mention how to access this node to be decreased.

**Edit:**

I should use pointers that point to each node of the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but if you have the key to your 'arbitrary node' couldn't you just use an `O(lg n)` time lookup to find it, and then decrease it using the algorithm you found online?